# Can I use unmanaged C++ code to reduce calculation costs in a C# project?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I want to use a c++ project to do some calculations for a c# project and return the results.

I was wondering if I would benefit a more efficient calculation speed in c++ if I do so? 
Would still be efficient if I wrapped the native code in c++/cli?

Are there any examples out there?
Just as simple example say you have two double values A and B in C#, how would you have c++ project to receive A and B and a string value "plus" or "times" to calculate and return A + B or A * B?

Comment: Simple calculations like that are not going to be significantly faster in unmanaged code.  I would build in using the frameworks that make you the most productive, get something that _works_, see where the most time is spent, and try to improve _that_.  Otherwise you're just guessing.

Comment: There are tons of questions/articles on interop between native (C++) and managed (C#) code ranging from just launching executable to deep integration with interfaces/callbacks passing data back and forth. It is unclear why all that available information did not help in your case...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: would you please provide some links to any of those resources?

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=interop+between+native+(C%2B%2B)+and+managed+(C%23)+code.

Comment: I found this tutorial: https://drthitirat.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/combine-gui-of-c-with-c-codes/ not exactly what I am looking for though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Process.Start();` to spawn your optimized program.  You will be able to pass parameters and even read the output.  Start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You've got two separate issues in your question: "How do I", and "Should I".

If you're having problems with the "How do I", please post a question with the specific code you have, and what problems you're having.

"Should I" is somewhat of a nebulous question: It depends a lot on the type of calculations you're trying to do. These questions often have no one right answer. (Also note that this type of question is often offtopic for Stack Overflow for that very reason, so this question may be closed.)

For some types of calculations, the C++ compiler might produce more efficient code than the .Net Jitter. For some types, it won't make a difference. C++ would also let you do things like using the GPU to perform the calculations.

Also, consider how long it will take you to write this optimized code, and how often you're going to run it. If this needs to run overnight once a month, maybe a couple hours to run is fine.